# DIF-DIF anaysis with a sample of multipe countries and treatments

Tags: difference-in-difference

For my research I collected board structure data of companies from 21 European countries of which 9 treatment group(before: mandatory one-tier or two-tier, after: choice between one-tier or two-tier) and 12 control group (mandatory one-tier or two-tier). 
I would like to investigate the effects of new regulations in the treatment countries. These regulations were implemented on several dates (multiple treatment periods) in all 9 treatment countries. Therefore, I have multiple countries and multiple treatment periods to implement in my DIF-DIF equation.

Is it possible to conduct a DIF-DIF analysis for the whole sample of countries (21) that specifies the effect of every regulations per country?

Thanks in advance!
Jan Peter